# How to set words to all capitals using windows 7 dictation

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking, voice-command

When I'm dictating, sometimes I want all the words to be all capitals.  Then I want to turn this off.

Comment: Have you tried yelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/customer-portal/documentation/userguide/chapter6/ug_chapter6_capitalize_text.asp)

> **Dictating next word in all capital letters**
>
> When you're dictating, you can enter a word in all capital letters by
>   saying "All Caps" and then the word. For example, say "All Caps
>   please" to get PLEASE. In the Medical Edition, you can choose to have
>   important words appear in all caps automatically. See Capitalizing
>   critical words for emphasis in Medical Edition on page 87.
>
> **Dictating consecutive words in all capital letters**
>
> When you want to dictate consecutive words in all capitals, you can
>   turn all capitals on and then turn them off when you've finished. To
>   dictate consecutive words in all capitals: Say "All Caps On" to turn
>   all capitals on (like pressing the CAPS LOCK key). Dictate the words
>   that you want to appear in all caps. For example, say "the end" and
>   Dragon types THE END Say "All Caps Off" to turn all capitals off.

Comment: Thanks.  Those instructions are from Dragon NS.  Will they also apply to Windows-7 built-in voice-to-text dictation?  (Maybe Microsoft uses Dragon?)

Comment: Sorry, from the tag list on your question I thought that you were asking about Dragon NS. My bad.

Comment: According to [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-speech-recognition-commands#1TC=windows-7) Windows 7 dictation provides the "All caps" and "no caps" commands. Do those suit your needs?

Comment: Yep, that works.  Thanks. Best of all, those commands apply after saying a phrase and pausing, then saying those commands.